# Cypress button click too quick to assert my test

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, response, ui-automation

I want to assert that when I click my button the button becomes temporarily disabled as the API call behind is made before returning being enabled again.

My problem is that the response the call makes when clicking the button is indeterminate, so the test sometimes passes and sometimes fails, obviously slower is better. My code is

```js
cy.get('.mybutton')
  .should('not.be.disabled')
  .click()
  .should('be.disabled');
```

Can I get this to always pass?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your test is using the result of `.click()` which is advised to be unsafe.

> ### [**click()**](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click)
>
> Click a DOM element.
>
> It is unsafe to chain further commands that rely on the subject after .click().

```js
cy.get('.mybutton')
  .should('not.be.disabled')
  .click()
cy.get('.mybutton')
  .should('be.disabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intercept the call, [you can add a delay](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Convenience-functions-1) to ensure you have enough time to check that the button is disabled.

```js
cy.intercept('/foo', (req) => {
  req.on('response', (res) => {
    res.setDelay(10000); // 10s
  });
});
```

You shouldn't need to modify the test code you provided, as that just *should work*, once the intercept is properly adding the delay to the call.

Comment: So we intercept on the call the button makes when clicked?

Comment: Yep! You'll want to set up the intercept _before_ the button is clicked, so that it's listening for the call to happen.

Answer (score -1):

Use `cy.waitUntil()` with custom conditions: If the timing is inconsistent and a fixed delay isn't reliable, you can use a custom condition with `cy.waitUntil()` to repeatedly check for the desired state until it's met. This approach allows you to add more flexibility to your test.

```js
cy.get('#your-button').click();

cy.waitUntil(() => 
  cy.get('#expected-element').should('be.disabled'), 
  { timeout: 5000, interval: 500 }
);
```